# Executar uma função ao carregar a pagina, JavaScript e Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou fazendo uma pagina de cadastro, e preciso relacionar um colaborador a uma empresa, mas para isso eu preciso quando a pagina carregue eu já tenha uma as empresas em uma lista>

Eu já estou recebendo as empresas em uma lista, o problema e fazer o objeto empresas estar carregado assim que a pagina carrega.

Está e minha função do Angular:

```
  $scope.colaborador = {};
    $scope.empresas = {};

    //Lista todas empresas para cadastro do colaborador
    $scope.getEmpresas = function () {
        var url = "cadastro-colaborador-empresa";
        MainService.get(url).then(function (cb) {
            location.href = 'cadastro-colaborador';
            $scope.empresas = cb;
        });
    };


    $scope.cadastrarColaborador = function () {
        var url = 'cadastra-colaborador';
        MainService.post(url, {colaborador: $scope.colaborador}).then(function (cb) {
            if (cb.idPessoa !== undefined) {
                location.href = 'index';
                $scope.colaborador = {};
                $scope.empresas = {};
            } else {
                $scope.alertaErro = cb;
                $("#myAlert").show();
            }
        });
    };
```

Estou usando o vRaptor e Java também, a funcção `cadastra-colaborador-empresa` retorna a lista de empresa para o objeto empresas.

Eu tentei chamar a pagina assim `<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/administrador/cadastro-colaborador" ng-click="getEmpresas()">Cadastrar Colaborador</a>`

Mas não deu certo, meu select esta assim

```
 <select ng-options="empresa.idEmpresa as empresa.nome for empresa in empresas" ng-model="colaborador.empresa"></select>
```

A ideia e ter as empresas carregadas nesse select,se algum tiver uma ideia de como fazer ficarei grato.

Comment: Porque não chama a função `$scope.getEmpresas()` no seu controller?

Comment: Eu sou inciante em Angular e javascript não sei muita coisa , então dentro do próprio controller do angular eu ja posso chamar a função ? vou tentar aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode chamar sua função dentro do próprio `Controller`, dessa forma ela irá ser chamada assim que a página abrir.

EX:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.buscar = function() {
        $scope.nome = 'Nome Teste';
    }
    //Chamando a função buscar
    $scope.buscar();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 {{nome}}
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, sou novo em Angular e JavaScript, minha noção as vezes me atrapalha a fazer coisas simples, obrigado pela ajuda, agora posso resolver muitas outras coisas que estavam com problema no meu código.

Comment: Boa sorte e bons estudos.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar uma tag script logo abaixo do seu body:

```
<script>
  document.ready(function(){
    $scope.getEmpresas();
  });
</script>
```

Apesar de não ser a única solução :)